# Get the first index of asssoc array in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a following assoc array:

[image]

```html
45111 => array:16 [▼
    "სქესი" => array:1 [▶]
    "ასაკი" => array:1 [▶]
    "შემოსავალი" => array:1 [▶]
    "შემოსავლის ტიპი" => array:1 [▶]
    "Existing PMT" => array:1 [▶]
    "min(payment cnt)" => array:1 [▶]
    "guarantor" => array:1 [▶]
    "reqeusts last 3m / req last 12m" => array:1 [▶]
    "micro loans cnt last 12m (closed)" => array:1 [▶]
    "micro loans cnt last 3m (closed)" => array:1 [▶]
    "loans deliquency days" => array:1 [▶]
    "Past PMT" => array:1 [▶]
    "RiskGrade" => array:1 [▶]
    "ProbabilityOfDefault" => array:1 [▶]
    "Total" => array:1 [▶]
    "penalties paid" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 90.0
    ]
  ]
```

I'd like to iterate over the second array using first index. However, it returns "Undefined offset" exception. I guess $v[0] is not supported in blade. What is the correct way to do this?

```
@foreach ($creditInfo as $k => $v)
   @foreach ($v[0] as $y => $x)
      <tr>
      <td>{{$y}}</td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please edit question and repost as code, not as embedded image.

Comment: I've added a snippet for that

Answer (score 0):

It's just executing PHP so to say it's not supported in Blade makes no sense.  The error happens because `$v[0]` does not exist as 0 is an undefined offset.  `$v['Total']` would be fine though and would return an array.

Since the first key is `სქესი`, 0 isn't going to work but if you are only concerned about the first item, you can use `current` to grab the first.

```
@foreach ($creditInfo as $k => $v)
    @foreach (current($v) as $y => $x)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$y}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

That will loop through the array in `$v['სქესი']`